# Difficulty removing hot water faucet spindle

Tags: plumbing-fixture

We have a leaky hot water faucet in the bathroom. Every other how-to video makes removing the spindle (for replacement) look easy with just some sort of collar to remove first. Our assembly (see pics) is proving more difficult. Every time I attempt to loosen this collar, the whole faucet assembly below the sink just turns in unison. Tried some WD-40 to see if that would help but to no avail. Sink and faucet installed before we moved in. No visible marking on faucet to deduce [image: the brand. Anybody else have a similar s]ituation?[image]

Comment: How about a picture from under the sink? There's got to be something down there you can put a basin wrench on to hold it while someone else turns from the top. (Yup, this is going to be a 2-man job...)

Comment: @FreeMan  I guess you learnt the same way.  By trying to stretch one arm under.

Comment: Nah @crip659, mostly by being an amateur home plumber. I know that there's no way _I_ could figure out how to crawl under a sink, get a wrench on a nut down there, then hold it there while I get enough of me out from under to put another wrench on top... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is either 2 person job or one person with right tools.

For one person job use one wrench to clamp and old the bottom part.

Now you should be able to unscrew the top part.